# How can i set Default value for HiddenFieldFor In Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html.hiddenfor

i am using HiddenFor with model binding which is binding value to it.
i want to reset the binded value to zero.How can i do it?

i tried this but it is not working...

```
<% foreach (var item in Model ) { %>
 <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID,new { @value="0"})%>
 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create your own helper extension for that:

```
public static MvcHtmlString HiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

    var input = new TagBuilder("input");
    input.MergeAttribute("id", helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(propertyName)));
    input.MergeAttribute("name", helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName)));
    input.MergeAttribute("value", value.ToString());
    input.MergeAttribute("type", "hidden");
    input.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(input.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the `ID` property of your model in the controller action to `0`.

Comment: K understood .but i need to do the processing on the ID property of my model means i am using it on other field also.

Comment: In this case I am afraid you will have to generate the HTML manually without using the `HiddenFor` helper. Also why do you need a hidden field whose value is always set to `0`? Do you have some other javascript code that would later modify the value?

Comment: yes i have the javascript code which would change the hidden field value on check box check.